# How to access query parameter with hyphen in nextJS 13?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

I have a route that contains a query parameters with hyphen:

`/?previous-page=building-details`

In my Page:

```
import EnergyEfficiency from "@/ui/energy-check/energy-efficiency"

const Page = ({
  params,
  searchParams,
}: {
  params: { id: string }
  searchParams: { modernization: string; previousPage: string }
}) => {
  const { modernization, previousPage } = searchParams

  console.log(previousPage) // undefined

  return <EnergyEfficiency addressID={params.id} />
}

export default Page
```

I want to access that parameter from the page props, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily access query params of your route using [useSearchParams](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params) hook

> useSearchParams is a Client Component hook that lets you read the current URL's query string.

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'

export default function Page() {

  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
  // url => http://localhost:3000/?previous-page=building-details
  const previousPage = searchParams.get('previous-page')
  console.log('previousPage', previousPage) // logs 'building-details' to the console

  return (
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
  )
}
```

---

If a [Server Component](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components) is what we talk about here, here's the way

Attention! You should be using the app folder. To implement this one, add a contact folder under the app folder and then add page.tsx file inside your new contact folder and copy paste the code below.

File Structure

[image: File Structure]

```
const Page = ({
  searchParams,
}: {
  searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined }
}) => {
    const contactWay = searchParams["contact-way"]
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Contact Page</h1>
            <h2>Contact Way: {contactWay}</h2>
        </>
    )
}

export default Page
```

Now visit http://localhost:3000/contact?contact-way=email

and see the result:

[image: Result]

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/upbeat-leaf-6scwsm?file=%2Fapp%2Fcontact%2Fpage.tsx%3A3%2C5